# How to collect requestURL and responseTime in a CSV file for easy filtering while running the tests using RestAssured

Tags: java, csv, automated-tests, ui-automation, rest-assured

I have designed my RestAPI tests using the RestAssured framework. In the below code I want to collect requestURL and responseTime in a CSV file for easy filtering while running the tests using RestAssured for easy filtering. Basically I want the requestQuery.getURI()) and response.getTime() to be in the CSV file after each run. If anybody has tried this, can you please share it?

```
**Util file**

    public void submitRequest(String method) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    LogUtil.log(String.format("Request URI: %s", requestQuery.getURI()));
    LogUtil.log(String.format("Submitting %s request", method.toUpperCase()));
    if (LogUtil.isConsoleLogEnabled()) {
        request.log().all();
    }
    response = switch (method.toUpperCase()) {
        case "GET" -> RestAssured.given(request).get();
        case "POST" -> RestAssured.given(request).post();
        case "PUT" -> RestAssured.given(request).put();
        case "DELETE" -> RestAssured.given(request).delete();
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid method type" + method);
    };
    LogUtil.log(response.asPrettyString());
    if (LogUtil.isConsoleLogEnabled()) {
        response.then().log().all();
    }
    LogUtil.log("Response Time: " + response.getTime() + " ms");
    if(isAssertResponseTime && (response.getTime() > maxResponseTime) )
    {
        LogUtil.log(String.format("Response time exceeds the threshold: %s %s", response.getTime(), requestQuery.getURI()),"Warning");
    }
    responseJsonPath = response.jsonPath();
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't show the problem of writing csv file? Go to chatgpt and ask the way to write to file.